# How to match JSON-LD markup with REGEX?

Tags: html, regex, json-ld

I’m attempting to match an entire json-ld entry, regardless of specific markup, line breaks, etc.

Why doesn’t something as simple as this work:

```
    \<script type\=\"application\/ld\+json\"\>(.*?)\<\/script\>
```

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Recipe",
  "author": "John Smith",
  "cookTime": "PT1H",
  "datePublished": "2009-05-08",
  "description": "This classic banana bread recipe comes from my mom -- the walnuts add a nice texture and flavor to the banana bread.",
  "image": "bananabread.jpg",
  "recipeIngredient": [
    "3 or 4 ripe bananas, smashed",
    "1 egg",
    "3/4 cup of sugar"
  ],
  "interactionStatistic": {
    "@type": "InteractionCounter",
    "interactionType": "http://schema.org/Comment",
    "userInteractionCount": "140"
  },
  "name": "Mom's World Famous Banana Bread",
  "nutrition": {
    "@type": "NutritionInformation",
    "calories": "240 calories",
    "fatContent": "9 grams fat"
  },
  "prepTime": "PT15M",
  "recipeInstructions": "Preheat the oven to 350 degrees. Mix in the ingredients in a bowl. Add the flour last. Pour the mixture into a loaf pan and bake for one hour.",
  "recipeYield": "1 loaf",
  "suitableForDiet": "http://schema.org/LowFatDiet"
}
</script>
```

I expect the output to be everything inside the  tag.

Answer (score 1):

Here, we might want to bound our expression with an open json/ld tag as a start boundary, then collect all chars and newlines, and finally add a right boundary with closing script tag, maybe similar to:

```
(<script type="application\/ld\+json">)([\s\S]*)(<\/script>)
```

or

```
^(<script type="application\/ld\+json">)([\w\W]*)(<\/script>)$
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/0A9cty/1)

However, maybe here it would not be the best idea to user regular expressions and there should be so many methods that would do so much easier.

#### Test

```
const regex = /^(<script type="application\/ld\+json">)([\w\W]*)(<\/script>)$/gm;
const str = `<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Recipe",
  "author": "John Smith",
  "cookTime": "PT1H",
  "datePublished": "2009-05-08",
  "description": "This classic banana bread recipe comes from my mom -- the walnuts add a nice texture and flavor to the banana bread.",
  "image": "bananabread.jpg",
  "recipeIngredient": [
    "3 or 4 ripe bananas, smashed",
    "1 egg",
    "3/4 cup of sugar"
  ],
  "interactionStatistic": {
    "@type": "InteractionCounter",
    "interactionType": "http://schema.org/Comment",
    "userInteractionCount": "140"
  },
  "name": "Mom's World Famous Banana Bread",
  "nutrition": {
    "@type": "NutritionInformation",
    "calories": "240 calories",
    "fatContent": "9 grams fat"
  },
  "prepTime": "PT15M",
  "recipeInstructions": "Preheat the oven to 350 degrees. Mix in the ingredients in a bowl. Add the flour last. Pour the mixture into a loaf pan and bake for one hour.",
  "recipeYield": "1 loaf",
  "suitableForDiet": "http://schema.org/LowFatDiet"
}
</script>`;
const subst = `$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/KXJjPo/1)

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/KXJjPo/1).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Wow. Very nice explanation. Thank you. Although, those two regex aren’t working in the wild for me. Say, with [this page](https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/269707/mushroom-broccoli-and-cheese-stuffed-chicken/?internalSource=rotd&referringContentType=Homepage&clickId=cardslot%201). Regex might not be the easiest method generally, but my application has me limited to what I can do inside an iOS Shortcut. That’s basically regex ...and [JavaScript if I can handle as shown here.](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/agh6ro/using_javascript_in_your_shortcuts/)